# CTRL SHIFT Z Windows freezes

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I rename a folder on the desktop: write some letters, press `ctrl + z`. Undo works: all written leters are gone. Then I press `ctrl + shift + z` to Redo and desktop fezes. Then I press `ctrl + alt + del` and click task manager. Task manager appears and the desktop unfreezes. The same thing happens in Chrome, Edge browser, Word and everywhere I use `ctrl + shift + z`. Is there anything I can do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set of steps works fine on my computers here.

Start with the initial set of repair steps:

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Then run both:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

sfc /scannow

When these are complete, restart and test.

If DISM and SFC do not correct the issues, run a Windows 10 Repair Install to correct the problem. Use the Media Creation Link, second link, run in place and at the appropriate spot, use the option to Keep Everything (Default option)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was app called "Just Color Picker". Solution is to change it's hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

"Just Color Picker" was the answer for me also. Using ctrl+shift+z for redo in so many other programs but in MS products it always seemed to freeze my screen until I went in/out of Task Manager ... thank you @rtxndr it has been a bugbear for years

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1170673)